# How to move selected bone joints independently?

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I want to move few bones joints independently as shown below (to make an animation of the sitting):

[image: Screenshot]

**Is it possible in blender? If yes, how to make it?** It's important for me to front paws was not moved or the animation will look weird.

**P.S.** I use **Blender v.2.90.1**.

Comment: Not easy as it means that the spine axis center switch from bottom to top, there may be a way, a trick would be to give 2 armatures to your object, with completely different bone names, parent to the first armature then to the second so that you have 2 Armature modifiers, and switch from an armature to the other one (keyframe visibility) when you need to make the dog sit?